# org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap Unable to setup SSL support for LDAP

Tags: apache, ssl, openldap, tls1.2, jaas

I'm currently running an instance of OpenLDAP 2.4.45 as my authenticator for a Talend ESB container. I'm connecting to the LDAP using TLS and I've managed to get my JMS broker to connect and make use of the LDAP successfully using org.apache.activemq.jaas.LDAPLoginModule, however, when using org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule for web services, I get the following stack trace:

```
2017-08-11 19:04:13,828 | WARN  | qtp272427408-140 | LDAPLoginModule                  | 126 - org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules - 4.0.8 | Can't connect to the LDAP server: Unable to setup SSL support for LDAP: null
javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to setup SSL support for LDAP: null
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPOptions.setupSsl(LDAPOptions.java:178)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPOptions.getEnv(LDAPOptions.java:158)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPCache.open(LDAPCache.java:113)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPCache.doGetUserDnAndNamespace(LDAPCache.java:151)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPCache.getUserDnAndNamespace(LDAPCache.java:142)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule.doLogin(LDAPLoginModule.java:115)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule.login(LDAPLoginModule.java:54)
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.ProxyLoginModule.login(ProxyLoginModule.java:83)[org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot-4.0.8.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)[:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)[:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)[:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.JAASLoginInterceptor.handleMessage(JAASLoginInterceptor.java:141)[67:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)[67:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[67:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)[19:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)[92:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)[200:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)[200:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)[223:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)[198:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)[223:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[200:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)[223:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[199:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)[191:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[202:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[202:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_131]
```

My configuration file for my authenticator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

 <jaas:config name="KarafLdapConfiguration" rank="1">
    <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="required">
        connection.url=ldaps://ldap:4444
        connection.username=uid=user,ou=users,dc=base
        connection.password=password
        authentication=simple
        user.base.dn=ou=users,dc=base
        user.filter=(uid=%u)
        user.search.subtree=true
        role.base.dn=ou=groups,dc=base
        role.filter=(uniquemember=%fqdn)
        role.name.attribute=uid
        role.search.subtree=true
        ssl=true
        ssl.protocol=TLS
        ssl.algorithm=PKIX
        ssl.keystore=store
        ssl.keyalias=myalias
        ssl.truststore=trust
    </jaas:module>
  </jaas:config>

  <jaas:keystore name="store"
   path="file:///some/path/keystore.jks
   keystorePassword="secret"
   keyPasswords="secret" />

   <jaas:keystore name="trust"
   path="file:///some/path/truststore.jks
   keystorePassword="secret" />
</blueprint>
```

My suspicion here is that I'm missing the ssl.provider option in this configuration file. The documentation isn't clear on what this is expecting, though the source seems to be looking for a URI of some sort. I've spent quite a bit of time searching, but I can't find any information on what and SSL provider is outside of the companies that provide CA services. I don't know what URI this could be looking for. I'm not doing revocation checking, so not that. Any thoughts on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this a few days ago, figure I'll document the solution in case it helps anyone in the future.

The issue did turn out to be a missing ssl.provider field in the configuration file. The part that took some figuring out was the actual URI that was required. In my earlier experimentation, I was missing the base DN for the LDAP. Ultimately, the field should look like

```
ssl.provider=ldaps://<somehostname>:<port>/<baseDN>
```

so what I ended up with was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

 <jaas:config name="KarafLdapConfiguration" rank="1">
    <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="required">
        connection.url=ldaps://ldap:4444
        connection.username=uid=user,ou=users,dc=base
        connection.password=password
        authentication=simple
        user.base.dn=ou=users,dc=base
        user.filter=(uid=%u)
        user.search.subtree=true
        role.base.dn=ou=groups,dc=base
        role.filter=(uniquemember=%fqdn)
        role.name.attribute=uid
        role.search.subtree=true
        ssl=true
        ssl.protocol=TLS
        ssl.algorithm=PKIX
        ssl.provider=ldaps://ldap:4444/dc=baseDN
        ssl.keystore=store
        ssl.keyalias=myalias
        ssl.truststore=trust
    </jaas:module>
  </jaas:config>

  <jaas:keystore name="store"
   path="file:///some/path/keystore.jks
   keystorePassword="secret"
   keyPasswords="secret" />

   <jaas:keystore name="trust"
   path="file:///some/path/truststore.jks
   keystorePassword="secret" />
</blueprint>
```